# Wget: convert-links and avoid redownloading already fetched files?

Tags: wget, download

I am downloading data spread among multiple files that don't change once published.

Therefore `--timestamping` is not good enough, because it is constantly checking whatever resource is changed, which is, in my case, completely pointless.

`--no-clobber` would fit perfectly. Unfortunately it doesn't work with `--convert-links`  for some reason.

> Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only
>   --convert-links will be used.

I hoped that `--backup-converted` would help but it changed nothing (it works for `--timestamping`.)

Why `wget --convert-links --backup-converted --no-clobber --wait 1 https://example.com` ignores `--no-clobber` and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Hitting that same problem today. How did you solve it?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I never solved it (I would post answer if that would happen). In the end in my case redownloading fetched links was simpler than patching wget or switching to something else.

Comment: did you try `--continue`? this usually is meant to contiune a download previously aborted. but if the file already was fetched it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JTP I tried '-c', but the result was the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Any possibility of using rsync? You will have to have ssh access to the system. 
(I have never seen rsync used for http:// downloads.)

Something like this will get files you have never gotten and will re-pickup files that stopped downloading for some reason.

```
rsync -avzheP ssh root@192.168.0.100:/remotefolder/ /localfolder/
```

This may not work for you. Not enough information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use both `--convert-links` and `--no-clobber`. You will get this message:

`Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only --convert-links will be used.`

`wget` can accomplish what you want, if you specify `--convert-links` and `--timestamping`. But this will only work if the target site supplies the file timestamp info in the response headers.

Comment: This answer has nothing that was not mentioned in the very first revision (https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/177330/revisions) of my question.